# For each $x\in X$ there exists a neighborhood of x s.t $A\cap U\neq \emptyset$ for only finitely many $A\in\mathcal{A}$. Show that f is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

Hello I am doing this exercise where we let X and Y be topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a function. We suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of closed subsets of X, such that $\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}} A = X$. We assume that for every $A\in \mathcal{A}$ the restriction $f_{|A}: A\to Y$ of f to A is continuous. Furthermore we suppose that for each $x\in X$ there exists a neighborhood U of x such that the intersection $A\cap U$ is non-empty for only finitely many $A\in\mathcal{A}$. And I have to show that f is continuous.

I know that since $f_{|A}: A\to Y$ is continuous we have that for all open subsets $O\subseteq Y$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(O)$ is an open subset of A. And to show that $f: X\to Y$ is continuous I am thinking of showing that for each open subsets $O\subseteq Y$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(O)$ is an open subset of X, but this would be obvious wouldn't it since for all open $O\subseteq Y$ we have $f^{-1}(O)\subseteq A\subseteq X$?

Comment: No, $f^{-1}(O)$ need not be a subset of $A$, but $(f|A)^{-1}(O) \subset A$; in fact, $(f|A)^{-1}(O) = f^{-1}(O) \cap A$.

Comment: Okay then I am pretty much lost on how to get through with this exercise. Do you probably have an idea?

Comment: What was your method? Maybe it can be tweaked

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be a non-empty open set in $Y$, and let $V=f^{-1}[U]$; we need to show that $V$ is open in $X$. To do this, let $x\in V$, let $W_x$ be an open nbhd of $x$ that intersects only finitely many members of $\mathscr{A}$, and let $\mathscr{A}_x=\{A\in\mathscr{A}:W_x\cap A\ne\varnothing\}$; note that $W_x\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{A}_x$.

For each $A\in\mathscr{A}_x$ the function $f\upharpoonright A$ is continuous, so $V\cap A$ is relatively open in $A$, and there is an open $G_A$ in $X$ such that $V\cap A=G_A\cap A$. Let

$$G_x=W_x\cap\bigcup_{A\in\mathscr{A}_x}G_A\,;$$

clearly $G_x$ is open in $X$, and $G_x\subseteq V$. Now $x\in W_x\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{A}_x$, so there is an $A_x\in\mathscr{A}_x$ such that $x\in A_x$. And $x\in V$, so

$$x\in V\cap A_x=G_{A_x}\cap A_x\subseteq G_{A_x}\subseteq\bigcup_{A\in\mathscr{A}_x}G_A\,,$$

and therefore $x\in G_x\subseteq V$. Thus, $V=\bigcup_{x\in V}G_x$ and is therefore open in $X$.

Comment: But what is W ?

Comment: @Sara: A typo: as was pretty clear in context, it was just missing its subscript, which I’ve now added.